# Is this {'': [ {}, {}, {} ]} Dictionary of List of a Dictionary? How can I Split the inside values so I can print/process them separately?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I understand I really need Dictionary and List Comprehension understanding. Spent so much time reading all the articles here in stack overflow and else where but getting no where and more confused. Please someone help.

When I query database, basically I get a `<class 'dict'>` object back of `{'': [ {x1:1, y1:2, z1:3}, {...}, {...} ]}` syntax. e.g:

```
{'results': [{'Event Time': '2023-01-25T00:18:32.3900000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Norma.Cayshun', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\Norma.Cayshun has changed alert note SOUTHBAY-VM2 13.107.136.45 has rebooted. [].'}, {'Event Time': '2023-01-25T00:18:32.3900000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Norma.Cayshun', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\Norma.Cayshun acknowledged alert SOUTHBAY-VM2 13.107.136.45 has rebooted..'}, {'Event Time': '2023-01-16T01:55:05.1930000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef has changed alert note Server Node Down on NORTHLOBBY-VM5 [].'}, {'Event Time': '2023-01-16T01:55:05.1930000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef acknowledged alert Server Node Down on NORTHLOBBY-VM5.'}, {'Event Time': '2023-01-16T01:55:05.1930000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef has changed alert note SOUTHBAY-VM2 13.107.136.45 has rebooted. [].'}]}
```

I'm trying to get those x's, y's and z's value out separately so I can print them nicely or process them as needed. So something like this

```
1. 'Event Time': '2023-01-25T00:18:32.3900000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Norma.Cayshun', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\Norma.Cayshun has changed alert note SOUTHBAY-VM2 13.107.136.45 has rebooted. [].'

2. 'Event Time': '2023-01-25T00:18:32.3900000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Norma.Cayshun', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\Norma.Cayshun acknowledged alert SOUTHBAY-VM2 13.107.136.45 has rebooted..'

3. 'Event Time': '2023-01-16T01:55:05.1930000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef has changed alert note Server Node Down on NORTHLOBBY-VM5 [].'
```

There are folks with solution using Pandas/Numpy, Zip() functions, dreaded :-) Lambda() function etc... If you can help with simpler solution first that will be great. I'll understand issue better that way.

Here is sample code that I am testing with.

```
def query_database():
    result = {'results': [{'Event Time': '2023-01-25T00:18:32.3900000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Norma.Cayshun', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\Norma.Cayshun has changed alert note SOUTHBAY-VM2 13.107.136.45 has rebooted. [].'}, {'Event Time': '2023-01-25T00:18:32.3900000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Norma.Cayshun', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\Norma.Cayshun acknowledged alert SOUTHBAY-VM2 13.107.136.45 has rebooted..'}, {'Event Time': '2023-01-16T01:55:05.1930000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef has changed alert note Server Node Down on NORTHLOBBY-VM5 [].'}, {'Event Time': '2023-01-16T01:55:05.1930000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\christopher.Cheef acknowledged alert Server Node Down on NORTHLOBBY-VM5.'}, {'Event Time': '2023-01-16T01:55:05.1930000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef has changed alert note SOUTHBAY-VM2 13.107.136.45 has rebooted. [].'}]}
    return result


def display_data():
    result = query_database()
    print("{0}".format(result))

    for item in result:
        print(item)
        print(f">>> {result.values()}")


def main():
    display_data()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: So do you want to get the dictionaries inside the list as is? What types are 1. 2. and 3.?

Comment: Yeah correct, the inside dictionaries. 1, 2 and 3 are Bullet Points or say Serial Number of how many number of inner most dict. {} values. If 'result' had say 10 inner dictionary, the Bullet points would be 1, 2, 3, .... 9,10.

Comment: And do you need them to be separate variables, or are you keeping those results in some sort of data structure?

Comment: Doesn't have to be separate Variables. If I can somehow reference them Say like 
results[0][0]
results[0][1]
etc. I can if required use string.split() to get individual values. 

Tried this:
    `for item in result:`
        `print("{0}".format(item))`
        `print("{0}".format(type(result)))`
        `print("{0}".format(len(result)))`

This prints:
`results`
`<class 'dict'>`
`1`

Comment: `{[ {x1:1, y1:2, z1:3}, {...}, {...} ]}` is not possible. The outer `{}` has no `key:value` structure, so it's a set. But lists can't be elements of sets.

Comment: You need `for item in result['result']:`

Comment: @Barmar That was example. The query actual gets me key ''results'` in outer dictionary and value `[{}, {}, ...]`

Comment: Examples should still be valid.

Comment: Gotcha @Barmar. Sorry I'm a newbie on Stack Overflow.  And thank you, your solution worked. :-)

Comment: @Barmar I fixed the syntax. The question does show valid data, OP just misunderstood it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Did you not try looping over the list?

Comment: BTW, for tips, please read [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask). It covers things like showing what research you've tried and how to write a good title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example data you can just iterate through `results` key and print whatever you like:

```
results = {'results': [{'Event Time': '2023-01-25T00:18:32.3900000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Norma.Cayshun', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\Norma.Cayshun has changed alert note SOUTHBAY-VM2 13.107.136.45 has rebooted. [].'}, {'Event Time': '2023-01-25T00:18:32.3900000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Norma.Cayshun', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\Norma.Cayshun acknowledged alert SOUTHBAY-VM2 13.107.136.45 has rebooted..'}, {'Event Time': '2023-01-16T01:55:05.1930000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef has changed alert note Server Node Down on NORTHLOBBY-VM5 [].'}, {'Event Time': '2023-01-16T01:55:05.1930000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef acknowledged alert Server Node Down on NORTHLOBBY-VM5.'}, {'Event Time': '2023-01-16T01:55:05.1930000', 'AccountID': 'MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef', 'AuditEventMessage': 'User MICROSOFT\\Christopher.Cheef has changed alert note SOUTHBAY-VM2 13.107.136.45 has rebooted. [].'}]}
for row in results['results']:
    print(', '.join([f'{header}: {value}' for header, value in row.items()]))
```

```
Event Time: 2023-01-25T00:18:32.3900000, AccountID: MICROSOFT\Norma.Cayshun, AuditEventMessage: User MICROSOFT\Norma.Cayshun has changed alert note SOUTHBAY-VM2 13.107.136.45 has rebooted. [].
Event Time: 2023-01-25T00:18:32.3900000, AccountID: MICROSOFT\Norma.Cayshun, AuditEventMessage: User MICROSOFT\Norma.Cayshun acknowledged alert SOUTHBAY-VM2 13.107.136.45 has rebooted..
Event Time: 2023-01-16T01:55:05.1930000, AccountID: MICROSOFT\Christopher.Cheef, AuditEventMessage: User MICROSOFT\Christopher.Cheef has changed alert note Server Node Down on NORTHLOBBY-VM5 [].
Event Time: 2023-01-16T01:55:05.1930000, AccountID: MICROSOFT\Christopher.Cheef, AuditEventMessage: User MICROSOFT\Christopher.Cheef acknowledged alert Server Node Down on NORTHLOBBY-VM5.
Event Time: 2023-01-16T01:55:05.1930000, AccountID: MICROSOFT\Christopher.Cheef, AuditEventMessage: User MICROSOFT\Christopher.Cheef has changed alert note SOUTHBAY-VM2 13.107.136.45 has rebooted. [].
```

That being said, if you are going to do anything downstream in python with this data, I would toss the `results` values into a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(results['results'])
display(df)
```

```
+-----+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| idx |         Event Time          |          AccountID          |                 AuditEventMessage                 |
+-----+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|   0 | 2023-01-25T00:18:32.3900000 | MICROSOFT\Norma.Cayshun     | User MICROSOFT\Norma.Cayshun has changed alert... |
|   1 | 2023-01-25T00:18:32.3900000 | MICROSOFT\Norma.Cayshun     | User MICROSOFT\Norma.Cayshun acknowledged aler... |
|   2 | 2023-01-16T01:55:05.1930000 | MICROSOFT\Christopher.Cheef | User MICROSOFT\Christopher.Cheef has changed a... |
|   3 | 2023-01-16T01:55:05.1930000 | MICROSOFT\Christopher.Cheef | User MICROSOFT\Christopher.Cheef acknowledged ... |
|   4 | 2023-01-16T01:55:05.1930000 | MICROSOFT\Christopher.Cheef | User MICROSOFT\Christopher.Cheef has changed a... |
+-----+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Actual `display(df)` output in vscode, with jupyter addon, and solarized scheme:

[image]

Comment: Just updated that first example to use list comprehension and join to avoid getting the trailing comma

Comment: Hey @JNevill  how did you get the display(df) to print with rows|columns dashes. It look much pretty. The print(df), it does not print like that. Also the AuditEventMessage is cutoff, can I display the whole message?

Comment: `print(df)` is fine too. `Display()` didn't print like that, I just tossed the returned output into a [table->ascii-table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) converter for stackoverflow display. I pasted a pic of the actual `display(df)` output so there isn't confusion. You might want to consider `df.to_csv('somefile.csv')` as well. Not sure what kind of output is best for your needs, but the skies the limit.